# "Warning: Error in eval: could not convert n to scalar integer"

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, dplyr

I'm trying to make a shiny app that can let you choose different statistical methods to analyze some insurance data and then plot the results in a certain way. I want to be able to select a few values in the interface and the names of methods, and then have one button to trigger the creation of the model, and then another button to trigger the plot creation.

I'm pretty new to Shiny App and I'm getting an error message that I just cannot figure out.

"Warning: Error in eval: could not convert n to scalar integer"

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(insuranceData)
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(pls)
data(AutoBi)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Ratemaking Tool"),
  #fileInput("file", "Upload file"),
  actionButton("do", "Make Model"),
  actionButton("Go", "Make Graph"),
  selectInput("Model", "Model", c("lm", "glm", "pls")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
     sliderInput("percentiles",
              "Percentile Splits:",
              min = 1,
              max = 20,
              value = 5,round = TRUE),
  sliderInput("cv_splits",
              "Folds for K-fold validation:",
              min = 1,
              max = 10,
              value = 5,round = TRUE)),mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output){
values <- reactiveValues(df_data = NULL)


observeEvent(input$do, {
    dataInput <- isolate(reactive({
     t <- AutoBi %>% na.omit() %>% mutate(log.age = log(CLMAGE + 1),log.loss      =     log(LOSS + 1))
  train = slice(t,1:700)
  test = slice(t,701:nrow(t)) %>% mutate(log.age = log(CLMAGE + 1),log.loss =     log(LOSS + 1))
  t1 <- select(train,-c(log.loss,LOSS,CLMAGE))

  ctrl <- isolate(trainControl(method = "cv",number = input$cv_splits))
  model <- train(x = t1[,c(2,3,4,5,6,7)],y = train$LOSS,trControl = ctrl,
                 method = input$Model)
  preds <- predict(model,test[,c(2,3,4,5,6,9)])
  test$pred <- preds

  ordered <- test %>% arrange(pred) %>% mutate(quantile = ntile(pred,input$percentiles)) %>% group_by(quantile) %>%
    summarize(avg_loss = mean(LOSS),avg_prd= mean(pred)) %>% mutate(flag = as.factor(ifelse(avg_loss - avg_prd > 0,0,1)))
  values$df_data = ordered
  return(ordered)
}))
values$df_data = dataInput()
})

 observeEvent(input$Go,{
 output$distPlot <- isolate(renderPlot({
 ggplot(values$df_data)+ aes(quantile,avg_loss,size = 1) + geom_point() +     geom_point(aes(y = avg_prd,color = "avg_pred")) + ggtitle(paste("Statistical Learning Technique:", input$Model)) + 
    geom_linerange(aes(ymin = avg_prd,ymax = avg_loss,size = .1,color =   flag)) + guides(size=FALSE)
  }))
    })
 }

   shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Based on [this dplyr code](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/src/dplyr.cpp) it looks like that warning comes from `ntile`.  Might be a place to start troubleshooting from.

Comment: If you use `ntile` within `mutate_` instead of `mutate` things seem to work, although you need to use `"pred"` (the variable as a string).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ended up not using ntile at all since your solution forced there to be just one group. It's working as intended now though!